# How to reset camera after error in EDSDK

Tags: c++, edsdk

I have following problem when I control camera through EDSDK: if camera fails to shoot after EdsSendCommand, for example if autofocus fails, then it will return "device is busy" error for any subsequent commands. Is there any way to bring camera back to working state except for physically turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the camera button code to release busy event

My camera init

```
Private WithEvents MainCamera As EOSDigital.API.Camera
```

Cancel Busy

```
MainCamera.SendCommand(CameraCommand.PressShutterButton, 3)
MainCamera.SendCommand(CameraCommand.PressShutterButton, 0)
```